# Oracle 11g Update statement with Error ORA-00904

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-update, oracle12c

I have to run the following UPDATE query into an Oracle database.

```
UPDATE Appliance
 SET Appliance.IdApplianceType =
 (
 SELECT AT.id
 FROM Appliance A INNER JOIN ApplianceType AT
 ON UPPER(A.typeName) = UPPER(AT.name)
 AND Appliance.id = A.id)
```

The objective is to find the match between records of Appliance.typeName and ApplianceType.name and set the ApplianceType.id (primary key) in the Appliance.IdApplianceType (FK ApplianceType) (*Note: In a 2nd step normalize Appliance table removing Appliance.typeName column and to use IdApplianceType like relation.*)

In oracle 12c(and sqlserver 2008+) it works while **in version 11g doesn't work.**

I report the error below

```
QL Error: ORA-00904: "APPLIANCE"."ID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 - "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:
*Action:
```

Any help will be appreciated :)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra `join` seems unnecessary.  Why not just use this simpler version?

```
UPDATE Appliance
    SET Appliance.IdApplianceType =
        (SELECT AT.id
         FROM ApplianceType AT
         WHERE UPPER(Appliance.typeName) = UPPER(AT.name)
        );
```

Comment: I suppose without the final AND